# How to load data from a csv file into a table using Teradata Studio

Tags: csv, teradata

**Hi everybody,**

someone here may help me on that? I have to load data from a csv file into a table but I have no idea how.

There are about 12 million records into the csv file.

thanks

Comment: What technology is the table? What technologies are you proficient in? What have you tried already? Is there any more information you can add here?

Comment: The easiest way would be downloading Teradata Studio and the follow the approach described on DevEx: http://developer.teradata.com/tools/articles/transitioning-from-sql-assistant-to-studio-express the "Load Data into a Table" part.

Comment: Use bteq it has a built-in csv import option method. Easy to handle and cheap.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have loaded data into Teradata using the IMPORT function available in the TERADATA SQL Assistant.

But handling this amount of data I am not sure whether the method I explain you below will be efficient enough.

However, you may try something like the below:

If you are using TERADATA SQL Assistant:

1. Goto FILE menu-> click IMPORT option
2. You should have a table ready with all the required columns in your CSV file 
   and correct datatype.
3. In SQL Assistant, write the below query:

> `INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES(?,?,?,?....);`

4. Once you execute the above query TERADATA will ask for the file from which you want to import the data, you just need to browse and select your file and the import will begin.

P.S: Since you have 12 m records, it will definitely take lot of time.

Comment: In SQL Assistant 15.10, I could only get this to work with a tab-delimited input file, not a CSV file.

Comment: @MattWenham you can set the delimiter in Tools > Options > Export/Import, choosing commas rather than the default; tab

Comment: Note you also need a table in which to write the CSV data. You can do this by making a volatile table like this (for a 2-column table): 

`create volatile table TABLE_NAME(value1 integer not null, value2 integer) 
primary index (value1)
on commit preserve rows;`

Answer (score 0):

SQL assistant is not the way to load a file with that kind of volume.  Either use fload if loading an empty table otherwise use mload.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of table are you going to load data? (empty or containing data)

If you are going to load data in a staging table (empty table) then Fastload is the best and quickest method to load data in Teradata.

If table already has data then you can use Multiload (mload) to load data.

If you share your table DDL then it would easier to build Fastload or Multiload script for loading data.